# Set addition, subtraction, union between instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

What method(s) do I need to define in my class to be able to add together the following:

```
combined_set = set('a') | MyInstance
# want to get set(['a', MyInstance]) // instance is hashable
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'set' and 'MyInstance'
```

Comment: `|` is the operator for set union, can you be more specific about what you’re trying to do?

Comment: I forgot to explain myself: Your title, the actual question in your post, and the attempted solution all point towards wanting to make `MyInstance` implement set operations. Your desired output, on the other hand, indicates that you're simply trying to add an object to a set. Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unions, intersections, differences and symmetric differences of sets using the overloaded operators `|`, `&`, `-` and `^` have to be done on *two sets*, not a set and a single element. But you can write `{MyInstance}` instead of `MyInstance` to have a set containing that single element.

```py
>>> the_set = {'a'}
>>> element = 'b'
>>> the_set | {element}
{'a', 'b'}
>>> the_set & {element}
set()
>>> the_set - {element}
{'a'}
>>> the_set ^ {element}
{'a', 'b'}
```

As HeapOverflow points out, if you use the `union`, `intersection`, `difference` or `symmetric_difference` methods instead of the overloaded operators, the argument only needs to be an iterable, not necessarily a set; but that doesn't help in your case.

Comment: That's true for the operators but not quite for the methods. For example, `{'a'}.union('b')` successfully results in `{'b', 'a'}`, I don't have to write `{'a'}.union({'b'})`. Though I admit I'm a bit sneaky here, making it look like I can just write an element when that's not exactly what happens :-). But it's not a set, either.

Comment: Yes, that works because a single-character string is iterable, and if you iterate over it you just get the string itself as the only element. That's rarely going to be the use-case, but I've edited to clarify that I meant the overloaded operators (which don't have this behaviour).

Answer (score 3):

You could do it one of these ways:

```py
combined_set = set(('a', MyInstance))

combined_set = set('a') | { MyInstance }

combined_set = set('a')
combined_set.add(MyInstance)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a

```
__ior__(self, value)
```

for your class.

where value can be booth a set or another instance of your class.

But of course your class need to inherit from set.